# Assign "empty" to a Stringbuilder object

Tags: c#

Can anyone say me why when using this block of code :

```
   StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(strSource);

                for (int i = Start; i <= End-1; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = '';
                }
```

I get an error in the "for" loop: literal empty character.

On the other hand, this works:

```
temp[i] = ' ';
```

Comment: What is not clear about it? `''` denotes a literal of type `char`, `""` of type `string`. What would be the char you describe in `=''`?

Comment: On a sdie note `i <= End-1` is the same as `i < End`

Comment: I just want to delete this char!

Comment: @ArnaudAd You can't delete characters this way, that's not how things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reinvent the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove.aspx) method:

```
if (End > Start)
    temp.Remove(Start, End - Start);
```

`''` is not valid because single quotes introduce a `char` literal, which must always be one `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Characters must have a value.

Instead, you should write

```
temp.Length = 0;
```